# Adding numpy arrays in specific way

Tags: python, numpy

I have three numpy arrays.

```
   import numpy as np
   a=np.array((1,2,3,4))
   b=np.array((2,3,4,5))
   c=np.array((3,4,5,6))
```

and I want to add these arrays in the way

```
   a : [1  2  3  4]
 + b :    [2  3  4  5]
 + c :      [ 3  4  5  6]
   =   [1  4  9 12 10  6]
```

Is there any simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One intuitive way (although inefficient) would be to create an intermediate array of zeros, then fill in  each row with the values in `a`, `b`, `c`, ... with the appropriate column shift. Once you have this array you can just sum over the rows to get the result you want:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array((1,2,3,4))
b = np.array((2,3,4,5))
c = np.array((3,4,5,6))

arr_list = [a, b, c]

nr = len(arr_list)
row_lengths = [len(aa) for aa in arr_list]
nc = np.max(row_lengths) + nr - 1

digits = np.zeros((nr, nc), a.dtype)

for ii, aa in enumerate(arr_list):
      digits[ii, ii:(ii + row_lengths[ii])] = aa

print(digits)
# [[1 2 3 4 0 0]
#  [0 2 3 4 5 0]
#  [0 0 3 4 5 6]]

print(digits.sum(0))
# [ 1  4  9 12 10  6]
```

A faster method would be to compute the output directly, without creating the intermediate 2D array

```
out = np.zeros(np.max(row_lengths) + nr - 1, a.dtype)

for ii, aa in enumerate(arr_list):
    out[ii:(ii + row_lengths[ii])] += aa

print(out)
# [ 1  4  9 12 10  6]
```

Comment: What about: `np.array([1,2,3,3,2,1]) * np.arange(1,7)` ? :)

Comment: @cel Well OK, that would work for the OP's specific example but not for the general case where a, b, and c are arbitrary.